# Trouble in running application .jar from built path

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program using serial communication. I used the Java Communications API (comm.jar) for this. My program works when I run it from my IDE (NetBeans), but my application .jar didn't run when I tried to run from its built location(from 'C:\Users\Bipin panday\Documents\NetBeansProjects......\dist' folder).

The code for my program that does not work when run from the built location is:

```
CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        int i = 0;
        String[] r = new String[10];
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
            r[i] = portIdentifier.getName();//+  " - " +  getPortTypeName(portIdentifier.getPortType()) ;
            i++;
        }

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(r));
    }                                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

        String com = selectedItem.toString();
        SimpleRead(com);
    }                                          

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        serialPort.close();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void SimpleRead(String com) {
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                if (portId.getName().equals(com)) {
                    //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                    try {
                        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
                    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    try {
                        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    try {
                        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
                    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
                    try {
                        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,
                                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                    readThread = new Thread(this);
                    readThread.start();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
                break;
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[25];

                try {
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        //int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                        inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    }
                    waiting(2);
                    String y = new String(readBuffer);
                    System.out.println(new String(readBuffer));
                    jTextArea1.setText(y);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you setup your classpath? An IDE "knows" where the classes and jars are but not a command line tool.